# How to prove this equality...

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\arctan(x)=\frac{(n-1)!}{(1+x^2)^{n/2}}\sin\left[n \arctan\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right]$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{d(\arctan x)}{dx}=\dfrac1{x^2+1}$$

Now $\dfrac{2i}{x^2+1}=\dfrac1{x-i}-\dfrac1{x+i}$

Using  [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Nth_Derivative_of_Mth_Power), $$\dfrac{d^n(1/x\pm i)}{dx^n}=\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}n!}{(x\pm i)^{n+1}}$$

Now write $1=r\sin A,x=r\cos A\implies r=\sqrt{x^2+1},\cot A=x$

Comment: can you explain any further